# Filtering SQL results by date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Here is my query for a maintenance dates list.

```sql
SELECT `checkdates`.`checkdateplanneddate`, `checkdates`.`checkdatevehicle`, `checktypes`.`checktype`, `checktypes`.`emailto`, `checktypes`.`daysnotice`
FROM `checkdates`
    , `checktypes`
WHERE `checktypes`.`checktype` = `checkdates`.`checkdatechecktype`;
```

The idea is..
Everyday the server will email customers to let them know which checkdates are coming, based on the days notice that is set for that type of check. (see image)

Currently it is showing all checkdates.

All i need to do is filter the list so it only shows the dates that are
"Todays date plus checktypes.daysnotice"

I have tried many different queries, but cannot seem to get the right combo.

Thank you in advance

I have attached an image to show that the data is available

[image: The data is available, but I need to filter the dates]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running. Is this MySQL?

Comment: this is a query i have run in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and assuming that you are running MySQL (as the use of backticks for quoting and the phpmyadmin screen copy indicate), you can use date arithmetics as follows:

```
SELECT cd.checkdateplanneddate, cd.checkdatevehicle, ct.checktype, ct.emailto, ct.daysnotice 
FROM checkdates cd
INNER JOIN checktypes ct ON ct.checktype = cd.checkdatechecktype
WHERE cd.checkdateplanneddate = current_date + interval ct.daysnotice day
```

The `where` condition implements the desired logic.

Side notes:

- Use standard, explicit joins! Implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause) is a very old syntax, that should not be used in new code
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read

Comment: I have added your select to a test page and i am not getting any results (i will need to be sure there are actually results to show) will check and let you know, thank you

Comment: I have checked and there wasn't checks available for the date range selected, changed the ct.daysnotice to a number and it has worked. Thank you for your help :)